# ggplot: Set colours with 2+ factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, geom-bar

I have a dataset with 2 factors, each with 2 levels. I want to make a grouped bar graph with 4 different colours.

The data looks like this:

```
TrialType Group yvar
TP         C     1
TP         E     2
TA         C     3
TA         E     4
```

I use this to make the bar graph using

```
ggplot(data=k, aes(x=V2, y=V3, fill=V1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", color="#000000") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#d7191c", "#FFBB45"), breaks=c("TA", "TP"))
```

And I get the [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN86f.png) graph.

Is there a way to make this graph so the bars go Dark red/light red/dark yellow/light yellow from left to right? So that the Groups are delineated based on red/yellow, and the trial type is delineated based on darkness?

Thanks a lot!
Mrinmayi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically like this, using `interaction` to get a unique color for each combination:

```
ggplot(data=k, aes(x=Group, y=yvar, fill=interaction(TrialType,Group))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", color="#000000")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("dark red", "pink", "yellow", "light yellow"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new variable by combining the first two factor variables and use that as your fill within aes(). See below.

```
library(tidyverse)

k <- tibble(TrialType=c("TP","TP","TA","TA"),
            Group=c("C","E","C","E"),
            yvar=c(1:4))

k$TrialType <- as.factor(k$TrialType)
k$Group <- as.factor(k$Group)

k$var4 <- as.factor(paste(k$TrialType, k$Group))

ggplot(data=k, aes(x=Group, y=yvar,fill=var4)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", color="#000000") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#C70039","#FFC300","#FF5733","#DAF7A6"))
```

And the plot looks like this. 
[image]

Comment: This works too!! I had tried combining the factors before, but ended up using it to set x, and "injecting" space between clusters of bars, but that was an absolute nightmare! Thanks for this solution!